# OpenRowset for CSV file returns blank or has errors

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, csv

So earlier, I am on the verge of creating a code that would import a CSV file that is machine generated, to our database. I created one in Excel, and I used this code

```
select *from openrowset('MSDASQL','Driver={Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv)}'
,'select * from D:\Test.CSV')
```

And it worked fine.
But when I am dealing with the actual data. The above code does not work.

So the CSV file contains a leading 18 row data which information could be dropped off (its just the name of the machine), the needed data is at the 19th row.

After searching, I found out a piece of code, and I tried it to the CSV file, which is

```
    SELECT *
        FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'D:\Data\sample\device1_2016-08-03_15-24-58.csv',
        FORMATFILE='D:\Data\sample\BCPFormat.xml',
        FIRSTROW = 19) AS a
```

but the data is blank!

I also tried this code

```
select * from OpenRowset('MSDASQL', 'Driver={Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv)};DefaultDir=D:\Data\sample\;','select * from device1_2016-08-03_15-24-58.csv')
```

The error states that

```
An error occurred while preparing the query "select * from device1_2016-08-03_15-24-58.csv" for execution against OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "(null)".
```

The server DBMS that we are using is SQL Server 2008 R2. We are also using MS Office 2010 to create spreadsheets.

Any ideas are welcome, thank you in advance!

EDIT:

I'll be including the screenshot of the CSV File.  [image: screenshot]

I'll also include the XML file (Because I have read that the FMT file is a XML file, kindly check if this is correct.)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <RECORD>
  <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=',' />
  <FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=',' />
  <FIELD ID="3" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=',' />
  <FIELD ID="4" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=','/>
  <FIELD ID="5" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=',' />
  <FIELD ID="6" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=',' />
  <FIELD ID="7" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=',' />
  <FIELD ID="8" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=',' />
  <FIELD ID="9" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=',' />
  <FIELD ID="10" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=',' />
  <FIELD ID="11" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=',' />
  <FIELD ID="12" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=',' />
  <FIELD ID="13" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=',' />
  <FIELD ID="14" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR='\n' />
 </RECORD>
 <ROW>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="NO." xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR" />
  <COLUMN SOURCE="2" NAME="Time" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR" />
  <COLUMN SOURCE="3" NAME="ms" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR" />
  <COLUMN SOURCE="4" NAME="degC1" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR" />
  <COLUMN SOURCE="5" NAME="degC2" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR" />
  <COLUMN SOURCE="6" NAME="degC3" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR" />
  <COLUMN SOURCE="7" NAME="degC4" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR" />
  <COLUMN SOURCE="8" NAME="degC5" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR" />
  <COLUMN SOURCE="9" NAME="degC6" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR" />
  <COLUMN SOURCE="10" NAME="A12345678901" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR" />
  <COLUMN SOURCE="11" NAME="A12345678902" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR" />
  <COLUMN SOURCE="12" NAME="A12345678903" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR" />
  <COLUMN SOURCE="13" NAME="A12345678904" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR" />
  <COLUMN SOURCE="14" NAME="A1234" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR" />
 </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

I have included the screenshot of the the CSV file in textfile

```
Vendor,GUARDIAN
Model,ZR-RX45
Version,Ver1.04
Sampling,10s
Total data points,0           
Start time,2016-08-03,15:25:01
End time,2016-08-03,15:24:59
Trigger time,2016-07-30,08:21:50
AMP Settings
CH,Signal name,Input,Range,Filter,Span
CH34, "PC-2",TEMP,TC_K,Off,250.000000,0.000000,degC
CH35, "PC-11",TEMP,TC_K,Off,250.000000,0.000000,degC
CH36, "PC-19",TEMP,TC_K,Off,250.000000,0.000000,degC
CH37, "PC-16",TEMP,TC_K,Off,250.000000,0.000000,degC
CH38, "PC-08",TEMP,TC_K,Off,250.000000,0.000000,degC
CH39, "PC-18",TEMP,TC_K,Off,250.000000,0.000000,degC
Logic/Pulse,Off
Data
Number,Date&Time,ms,CH34,CH35,CH36,CH37,CH38,CH39,Alarm1-10,Alarm11-20,Alarm21-30,Alarm31-40,AlarmOut
NO.,Time,ms,degC,degC,degC,degC,degC,degC,A1234567890,A1234567890,A1234567890,A1234567890,A1234
1,2016-07-30 08:21:50,000,+0.0,+0.0,+0.0,+0.0,+0.0,+0.0,LLLLLLLLLL,LLLLLLLLLL,LLLLLLLLLL,LLLLLLLLLL,LLLL
```

Comment: This worked fine for me after I created a dummy `.csv` file with two fields and 19 rows, set up a table in SQL with a matching schema, created a `.fmt` file for that table and ran a command identical to yours above (albeit with different file paths to my `.csv` and `.fmt` files). Perhaps you could post a sample of your `.csv` and `.fmt` files for us to reproduce the problem?

Comment: FWIW, in the DefaultDir of my test, I don't have the `\;` after the directory. Example: `DefaultDir=D:\Data\sample`

Comment: @3N1GM4 thank you for that insight, I have updated the code for added information.

Comment: @WEI_DBA Thank you for the insight, I tried removing the slash(/) also, it was slow at first, then the error popped up.

Comment: What does your `.CSV` look like if you open it in a text editor? I suspect the delimiter in your format file should be `','`, not `'","'`, as your CSV file might not have each value enclosed in double quotes.

Comment: Also, your data is in row 21, not row 19, so you'll need to change your FIRSTROW value as well.

Comment: I did all of your advices @3N1GM4 but sadly, it still returns zero rows...

Comment: That's strange, I have a `.CSV` and `.XML` format file which look identical to yours and it's working for me. Perhaps you could post the actual content of both of these files as code snippets so we can hopefully exactly reproduce the issue you're having? I'm also testing on SQL Server 2016, so maybe someone with 2008 to hand could try for you too?

Comment: @3N1GM4 for the column source part, should I put the exact column name of the CSV?

Comment: I did when I tested this here (as you have in the example you've given), but I don't think it actually matters - if you check the [MSDN page for XML Format Files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187833.aspx#Anchor_2), it states: "This column name is used to identify the column in the result set, and it need not correspond to the column name used in the target table.", so I think this is just an alias for the column in the generated resultset.

Comment: @3N1GM4 to tell you, this is the actual data.

Comment: Thanks, I do now seem to be able to reproduce the issue with either `.XML` format file, so there must be something wrong with either your `.CSV` - I'll see if I can figure it out (before someone else does!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because each row in your CSV doesn't have the correct number of fields, so it cannot be parsed. Even though you are only asking for rows 19 (or 21) onwards, the whole file still gets parsed.

You can resolve this by amending your `.CSV` file to have 14 fields (i.e. 13 commas) on every line:

```
Vendor,GUARDIAN,,,,,,,,,,,,
Model,ZR-RX45,,,,,,,,,,,,
Version,Ver1.04,,,,,,,,,,,,
Sampling,10s,,,,,,,,,,,,
Total data points,0,,,,,,,,,,,,      
Start time,2016-08-03,15:25:01,,,,,,,,,,,
End time,2016-08-03,15:24:59,,,,,,,,,,,
Trigger time,2016-07-30,08:21:50,,,,,,,,,,,
AMP Settings,,,,,,,,,,,,,
CH,Signal name,Input,Range,Filter,Span,,,,,,,,,,,,
CH34, "PC-2",TEMP,TC_K,Off,250.000000,0.000000,degC,,,,,,,
CH35, "PC-11",TEMP,TC_K,Off,250.000000,0.000000,degC,,,,,,,
CH36, "PC-19",TEMP,TC_K,Off,250.000000,0.000000,degC,,,,,,,
CH37, "PC-16",TEMP,TC_K,Off,250.000000,0.000000,degC,,,,,,,
CH38, "PC-08",TEMP,TC_K,Off,250.000000,0.000000,degC,,,,,,,
CH39, "PC-18",TEMP,TC_K,Off,250.000000,0.000000,degC,,,,,,,
Logic/Pulse,Off,,,,,,,,,,,,
Data,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Number,Date&Time,ms,CH34,CH35,CH36,CH37,CH38,CH39,Alarm1-10,Alarm11-20,Alarm21-30,Alarm31-40,AlarmOut
NO.,Time,ms,degC,degC,degC,degC,degC,degC,A1234567890,A1234567890,A1234567890,A1234567890,A1234
1,2016-07-30 08:21:50,000,+0.0,+0.0,+0.0,+0.0,+0.0,+0.0,LLLLLLLLLL,LLLLLLLLLL,LLLLLLLLLL,LLLLLLLLLL,LLLL
```

Then your command works:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'D:\some_location\device1_2016-08-03_15-24-58.csv',
                FORMATFILE='D:\some_location\BCPFormat.xml',
                FIRSTROW = 21) AS a
```

Comment: So, I have to change my CSV file to that kind of format sir? am I correct?

Comment: WOW! It did! Thanks!